# Carrying perfume while travelling

Tags: air-travel

I generally buy perfume from duty free shops at airport but obviously those perfumes don't get finished during the trip. So while coming back or in future trips I want to use those perfumes but as bottles are not sealed after being used once, my worry is that it might leak in check-in luggage. And in cabin baggage the liquid items are allowed in limited quantity.

Any ideas on how to carry an open bottle of perfume while travelling?

Comment: The duplicate is about carrying cologne bottles in hand luggage but the system is very likely to also work for perfume bottles in hold luggage. Make it extra safe by adding a good plastic (ziplock) bag around it.

Answer (score 1):

I would carry a limited amount of perfume on a smaller/sample container if travelling for a short time.

While I usually never had much problems with liquids, you may want to store such container in a water proof purse or inside a couple of plastic bags.

Beware of travelling with several bottles of perfume. If you read most of the travelling papers you sign to get in several countries, usually you are limited to a limited amount of perfume when travelling.

> Duty Free Allowance
>
> Delhi - 200 cigarettes or 50 cigars or 250g tobacco. 2 litres of
>   alcoholic liquor or wine. *2 ounces of perfume and 1/4 litre of toilet
>   water*.